# Multithreading and general hierarchy understanding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

Whenever my app gets a bit more complicated, it gets the to the point where the view is not refreshing as quick as i would like it to.

For example, if i have a player button, and whenever user hits that button, the button will change its image, and then the player will play some music, the image takes to long to change.

This happens no matter if there is a "SetNeedsdisplay" after the image change, or even if i user "preformSelectorOnMainThred" for the image change.

I added and code snap that shows what i mean:

```
- (IBAction)playButtonPressed:(id)sender {


//This is the  image change, plus a small animation that should happen:
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self.playButtonImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlayDiscButtonPressedMC"]];
    [[self superview] setNeedsDisplay];

    [self performSelector:@selector(animationInsertDisk) withObject:nil];

});

//This is the methus that will call the player to start playing, by delegate.
 [self performSelector:@selector(callDelegate) withObject:nil];;


}
```

What happens is, the change of image and the animation takes about 1-2 seconds before it happens, because of the "callDelegate" That comes after is! lets say i delete the "callDelegate" then the image and the animation will happen strait away!

I don't understand why this is happening, shouldn't the code that comes first happen first? 
Is it not enough that is happen on the main thread?

Any help here will be very much appreciated!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain

`dispatch_async` schedules everything in the block for immediate future. For example, if you call `dispatch_async` in a button tap handler, the code won't be executed until the method ends and the control is returned back to the system.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(callDelegate) withObject:nil];
```

is the same as writing

```
[self callDelegate];
```

It's a simple method call. And it's a blocking call. If the call takes some time, than everything in your UI has to wait (because you call it from the UI thread).

You code is basically identical to the following:

```
- (IBAction)playButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    [self callDelegate];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self.playButtonImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlayDiscButtonPressedMC"]];

       //no need for this here. Don't try to fix bugs by adding random code.
       //[[self superview] setNeedsDisplay];

       //performSelector just calls the method, so a direct call is exactly the same
       [self animationInsertDisk];
     });
}
```

Now, I am not sure what you want to achieve by that `dispatch_async`. You want the animation to start immediately and you are already on the main thread, so just do

```
- (IBAction)playButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.playButtonImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlayDiscButtonPressedMC"]];
    [self animationInsertDisk];

    [self callDelegate];
}
```

However, the "lag" is probably caused by the fact that you are starting your player from the main thread and blocking main thread for a while. I am not sure what exactly are you doing in `[self callDelegate]` but wrapping this call by `dispatch_async` could help.

Comment: Thank you! this very helpful! the code works better now. is there a reason to learn Multithreading or  dispatch_async is always the answer?

Comment: dispatch_async *is* multithreading. It's just one of the many ways to accomplish it.

Comment: @Catfish_Man If you are on the main thread and you schedule something on the main thread, then it's not actually multithreading.

Comment: Sure, there is a small subset of dispatch_async that doesn't result in using more than one thread. Basically every other use of it does though.